# How to view Google Calendar API JSON sample

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api

https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/cal_sample

How do you view the sample from this^ link? When I paste the link (from that^ link) into my browser, it says it is forbidden.  I am logged into a Google account.  I saw somewhere to "send it as a query."  What does that mean? Send it *where*? Via *what*?

Hoping to use this in some tests for code I have been writing in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you havent replaced your own email where it says developer-calendar@google.com in that sample you linked.